Laravel true polymorphic "many-to-many" relation
Laravel doc provides polymorphic "many-to-many" sample (pivot table taggables) with the following structure:
taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string

Here only one side is polymorphic (taggable_*).
My case is:

"instances" model family contains "field", "event" etc
"templates" model family contains "template_field", "template_event" etc
pivot table structure is:

template_registry:
    id
    instance_type - string
    instance_id - integer
    template_type - string
    template_id - integer

Which PHP code required to get something like:
$field->template

where template get linked template object (template_field / template_event)

to me it looks like the instance should be related to the template

@apokryfos Little bit complex - (field or event or ...) should be related to (template_*)

does a field relate to template_events or only template_fields?

@krisgjika yes, field -> template_field, event -> template_event, twin -> template_twin. Strongly, pivot table is not required: "template_id" field in table "field" more than enough. But for some reasons (to get common API) I have to use pivot table
